# Abandon Core data with iCloud and just Store / Load sqlite file of core data into iCloud storage

Tags: iphone, core-data, icloud

I'm making core data base app. 
and I struggled to sync core data via iCloud on multiple devices and It's failed. and I noticed tons of developers are in the same area with me.

https://devforums.apple.com/message/770288#770288

http://www.jumsoft.com/2013/01/response-to-sync-issues/

so please don't say there is better way to sync it or re-connect devices on syncing. 
We know that core data with iCloud is something that we have to avoid now. and I wasted half of year.

What I'm trying to do now is that just storing sqlite file of core data into iCloud storage so that I can use it like a syncing. (please don't say it's not sync. I don't want talk about conflict issue now) (and size of my sqlite file is quite small)
But I'm facing several issues and don't know what's the best way to do it. I don't have much time because I wasted much time already.

My Question is

1. Apple doesn't allow to store sqlite file on iCloud ?
2. Using UIDocument with iCloud is best way to do it?

   - I looked ray's tutorial from here
     http://www.raywenderlich.com/12779/icloud-and-uidocument-beyond-the-basics-part-1
     He use iCloud to sync these photo and It seems to work well. but I'm wondering if I also can do it with sqlite file. If yes, I think I will need to know how to convert sqlite file to nsdata and nsdata to sqlite like ray does with PNG file.

The reason why I'm looking UIDocument with iCloud is that It doesn't seem to work well that just storing and loading from the document folder of the iCloud ubiquetes storage. but UIDocument with iCLoud file syncing seems working quite well.

So Do you think It's good idea? who would go together?

Thanks

Bright Lee

Answer (score 1):

It's not that Apple doesn't allow SQLite files in iCloud-- it's that they warn you it's a **really** bad idea to do so. Corruption of the file is very likely, since the odds of changing it while it's open are high.

If your data store really is quite small, consider using the ubiquitous key value store instead.

Comment: but It's not that small.. I don't understand why it would be corrupted, Can you please tell me why?

Comment: my sceinario is that I would store sqlite file into iCloud when every time I call save method in core data, and load it when app launch. What would make bad ?

Comment: I thought there is no problem to do it because what I'm trying to do is just copy whole sqlite file not syncing.

Comment: They don't say specifically but it almost certainly has to do with coordinating access to the file between your app and the iCloud `ubd` daemon. If you were **very** careful to only access the SQLite file using `NSFileCoordinator` (coordinate a write, use the file, close it, and ensure changes are saved to the file before finishing coordinated access) then you *might* get away with it.

Comment: HI Tom Harrington, Can you please provide any Example Code for iCloude. Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Apple already provides a lot of sample code. If you have a specific question, ask it.